# Inheriting a abstract iterator interface

Tags: c++

I want to inherit a iterator for an container class. It should always have the same signature independent of the actual implementation.

But I have the problem that in `ContainerImpl` the returned `Container::Iterator` from `ContainerImpl::begin()` slices the overridden methods from `ContainerImpl::Iterator` back to the ones of `Container::Iterator`.

How can I force the more specific method to be used? 
Or can I rewrite my classes so that it behaves like that?

Below is a working example. It compiles at least against C++17.

```
#include <tuple>

using std::tuple;

class Container {
    // some code

public:

    class Iterator {
    public:
        virtual tuple<int, int> &operator*() {};

        virtual Iterator &operator++() {};

        virtual bool operator!=(const Iterator &rhs) const {};
    };

    virtual Iterator begin() = 0;

    virtual Iterator end() = 0;
};

class ContainerImpl : public Container {
    // some code

public:

    class Iterator : public Container::Iterator {
    public:
        Iterator(ContainerImpl &containerImpl) {
            // init
        }

        Iterator() {
            // end_iterator
        }

        virtual tuple<int, int> &operator*() override {
            // impl
        };

        virtual Container::Iterator &operator++() override {
            // impl
        };

        virtual bool operator!=(const Container::Iterator &rhs) const override {
            // impl
        };
    };

    virtual Container::Iterator begin() override {
        return Iterator{*this};
    };

    virtual Container::Iterator end() override {
        return Iterator{};
    };
};


int main() {
    ContainerImpl cont{};
    for (auto &entry : cont) {
        // here Container::Iterator::operator++() is called
        // instead of ContainerImpl::Iterator::operator++()
    }
}
```

edit:

Thanks! I read through your comments and figured out that I should try an static approach using templates. Performance is quite important for those iterators. This will need refactoring of other code where I use this code. But it should be moderate.

Here is what I came up with:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

using std::tuple;

template<class SubContainer>
class Container;


template<class ContImpl>
class Iterator {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Container<ContImpl>, ContImpl>::value, "ContImpl not derived from Container");
public:

    tuple<int, int> &operator*();

    Iterator<ContImpl> &operator++();

    bool operator!=(const Iterator<ContImpl> &rhs) const;
};



template<class SubContainer>
class Container {
public:
    Iterator<SubContainer> begin();

    Iterator<SubContainer> end();

};

class ContImpl;

template<>
class Iterator<ContImpl> {
public:
    ContImpl &container;

    Iterator(ContImpl &container, bool is_end = false) : container(container) { init(); }

    void init() {
    }

    tuple<int, int> &operator*() {
    }

    Iterator<ContImpl> &operator++() {
    }

    bool operator!=(const Iterator<ContImpl> &rhs) const {
    }
};

class ContImpl : public Container<ContImpl> {
public:
    Iterator<ContImpl> begin() {
        return Iterator<ContImpl>(*this, false);
    }

    Iterator<ContImpl> end() {
        return Iterator<ContImpl>(*this, true);
    }
};


int main() {
    ContImpl cont{};
    for (auto &entry : cont) {
        // Iterator<ContImpl>::operator++() is called.
    }
}
```

Comment: `begin()` and `end()` returns `Container::Iterator` so you have object slicing which is why the base operator are called.

Comment: You can't have polymorphic behavior without pointers or references. It's not a duplicate, but I proposed something that solves a similar problem on another post https://stackoverflow.com/a/46173609/817643

Comment: Combining operator overloading and virtual functions is almost always a sign of bad design. All this OOP iterator stuff just isn't idiomatic in C++. Use generic programming.

Comment: What @ChristianHackl means is that instead of (abstract) classes `Container` and `Iterator`, everywhere that *would use* those is `template <typename Container>` or `template <typename Iterator>`. You then *for free* get interoperability with `std` types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *dynamically* abstract away the differences between, say, `std::list<int>` and `std::vector<int>`, then what you want is [type erasure](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/12/06/type-erasure-part-ii/).  But do note that, using things like template template parameters, it is also possible to *statically* abstract over containers with similar interfaces (with the same or different element types), which (if it meets your requirements) should be significantly faster.

Regarding your template-based approach: while it might have value as documentation, the methods in `Container` are unnecessary: static polymorphism does not need any “base functions” to override.  If you remove them, you can do without that CRTP class entirely.  Then, similarly, you can replace the `Iterator` class template with a simple class `ContImpl::iterator`.

Of course, at that point all that’s left is the same interface compatibility as between the standard containers (which allows code like

```
template<template<class> class C>
C<int> makeInts(/*...*/);

void f() {
  auto d=makeInts<std::deque>(/*...*/);
  // ...
}
```

that I suggest above).  The interesting exercise is to hide a *different* container interface behind wrapper classes or with a traits interface.

Comment: I edited my question by adding a _static_ solution like you suggested. Is it what you meant?

Comment: Due to the actual matter where I use the structure being quite complex I would for now stick to the CRTP as it provides some space for documentation of a abstract interface.
Do you have an suggestion how I could realize this with a wrapper or traits interface or where to start to read. Especially with traits I have no experience. 
(I'm more into java as you maybe can see by my original code structure.)

Comment: @A.Bigerl: That should really be a separate question, since there doesn’t seem to be any existing explanation that’s trivial to locate and link.